# Django Ajax Post with HTML content using JSON.stringify then json.loads error

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a textarea within a form on a webpage that has "HTML" content.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<textarea id="my-textarea">
    <div class="this">Content here &amp; here!</div>
</textarea>
```

I fetch the content with Javascript and use encodeURIComponent to safely encode the string for AJAX JSON. and store it into a key/value array. (python dict)

```
// Javascript
var textarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea').value;
var data = {};
data['html'] = encodeURIComponent(textarea);
console.log(data);
// prints --> {html: "%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22this%22%3EContent%20here%20%26amp%3B%20here%3C%2Fdiv%3E"}

// In AJAX function.
var json = "data=" + JSON.stringify(data);
```

I then send the data to Django class based view and in post I have

```
# Python / Django
if request.is_ajax():
    print(request.POST)
    # prints --> <QueryDict: {'data': ['{"code":"<div class="this">Content here &amp; here</div>"}']}>

    data = request.POST.get('data', None)
    if data:
        data = json.loads(data)
```

This throws an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tr/dev/host-root/apps/trenddjango2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/tr/dev/host-root/apps/trenddjango2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/tr/dev/host-root/apps/trenddjango2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/tr/dev/host-root/apps/trenddjango2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tr/dev/host-root/apps/trenddjango2/django/common/views/dashboard/mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(TemplateDashboardMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tr/dev/host-root/apps/trenddjango2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tr/dev/host-root/apps/trenddjango2/django/common/views/dashboard/catalogue.py", line 550, in post
    data = json.loads(jsonData)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 22 (char 21)
```

I have found if I remove the **"" double quotes** within class="this", the string will load correctly.

My question is: How do I load a JSON string with double quotes in python even with it being escaped as %22 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\` to escape it.

```
json.loads('{"code":"<div class=\\"this\\">Content here &amp; here</div>"}')
```

this will work as you expected. The example below shows you how to escape.

```
'<div class="this">Content here &amp; here!</div>'.replace(/"/g, '\\\\"')
```

Result is:

```
"<div class=\\"this\\">Content here &amp; here!</div>"
```

Comment: Is there a way to escape "Double Quotes" in javascript so that Django receives the escaped string?

Comment: @DavidTovmasyan That worked for double quotes, but now Python throws error with the ampersand character. Is there a way to make a string purely JSON friendly between Javascript and Python? Or do I need to escape characters as they arise, what are those characters that need escaping and how would an ampersand be escaped? I used encodeURIComponent(textarea.replace(/"/g, '\\\\"')) which doesn't work.